# Submenu close function not working properly using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function that is semi-working to get a submenu to close when a user clicks anywhere else outside of the box. The function is selecting a class of sub.menu-open. If the event target does not equal the sub.menu-open and its parentNodes, (the elements inside the box), the function should execute "submenu-.open.style.display = "none". So, this works for a few clicks then it stops. The console reads Null after the first click. What I believe is that in my HTML there is no initial set class of sub.menu-open, which is why its saying Null at first. I add the submenu-open class with javascript. That is how I get the submenu to open in the first place. Is this possible to fix?

```
arrowButton.forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const subMenu = event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".sub-menu");
    subMenu.classList.toggle("open");
  })
);
-opening the submenu-

window.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {
  let box = document.querySelector(".sub-menu.open");
  if (event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box) {
    box.style.display = "none";
  }
});
--closing the submenu--
```

```
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu.open {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vw;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 6px auto;
  padding-left: 0.3rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  @include mobile {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: $footer-text;
    width: 60vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: $darkblue-headingtext;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```
 <li class="parent">
                <a href="#">Product</a>

                <img
                  class="menu-arrow mobile"
                  src="images/icon-arrow-dark.svg"
                  alt="arrow"
                />
                <img
                  class="menu-arrow desktop"
                  src="./images/icon-arrow-light.svg"
                  alt="arrow"
                />
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li>Overview</li>
                  <li>Pricing</li>
                  <li>Marketplace</li>
                  <li>Features</li>
                  <li>Integrations</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
```

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, @Felipe, I have executed your code, but It doesn't work as you mentioned now, please correct your issue

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)